# How to store immutable arrays in a variable stored property in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, immutability

I would like my class to have a stored property that can be assigned immutable arrays. If I do this:

```
class MyClass{
  var myItems:[String]
}
```

I can assign different arrays to my property, but the arrays will be mutable. If I do this:

```
class MyClass{
  let myItems:[String]
}
```

My array is immutable, but I can't ever change what's assigned to it. Is there any way to have my cake not mutate it too?

The best I've come up with is creating a wrapper around the array, then using that type for the property, like so:

```
class MyClass{
  struct ImmutableWrapper{
    let array:[String]
  }
  var myItems:ImmutableWrapper
}
```

…which is not exactly elegant.

Comment: I do not see how those things are even alike. Your first `myItems` is an array of Strings, not an array of "various immutable arrays". Nor do I see why the struct is inelegant; I think it's lovely.

Comment: I believe his code was errant and wasn't supposed to be an array of wrappers.  I've updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is oddly posed, since your first `myItems` is not an array of various arrays, it's just an array of Strings. However, I'll try to discuss the matter in a more general way.

Swift does not distinguish mutable from immutable arrays in the way Cocoa NSArray does. But why do you need this? *Cocoa* needs it because an NSArray is a *class*, so if it were mutable, it could be changed behind MyClass's back. But in Swift, Array is a value type, so that can't happen.

So what's the problem you are really trying to solve? You should ask yourself what contract you are trying to get outside objects to fulfill, and try to write that contract into the structure of MyClass. Your array of structs is a perfectly reasonable approach. I think, though, that what you're after here might actually be privacy, not immutability. For example, I might say this:

```
class MyClass{
    private var myItemsHidden = [String]()
    var myItems:[String] {
        get {
            return myItemsHidden
        }
        set {
            myItemsHidden = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Now, assuming MyClass is alone in its own file (because `private` in Swift means private to a file), `myItemsHidden` can be manipulated in any way you like from *inside* MyClass, so presumably MyClass knows not to mutate any subarrays or whatever it is you are trying to prevent. It is up to MyClass what it allows itself to do with `myItemsHidden`.

But from *outside* MyClass, `myItemsHidden` does not exist; there is only `myItems`, and the only thing anyone can do to it is get it and set it. (If they get it and change it, the original is unaffected. They cannot mutate the original.) If your purpose is to prevent anyone from outside setting `myItems` at all, delete the setter function:

```
class MyClass{
    private var myItemsHidden = [String]()
    var myItems:[String] {
        get {
            return myItemsHidden
        }
    }
}
```

Now `myItems` is merely a dispensed (vended) array and no more.

If the idea is that other classes should be allowed to add new arrays to an array of arrays, you could add a MyClass method that lets them do that. In other words, now that this thing is private, it is up to *you* what kind of access you give others to it. MyClass becomes the gatekeeper for what other classes can do with this value, because the value itself is hidden behind the `private` wall.

Comment: I was under the impression that an mutable array could still be changed behind the back of my class if I used one of its `mutating` methods. But it turns outSwift is awesomer than that. Mutating a property with a mutable method essentially assigns back to the property (it will still call that property's `didSet` handler, for example).

Comment: You make an important point, but this is not because Swift is awesome. (Swift may be awesome, but this is not why.) It is because an array is a  struct, and a struct is a value type. Mutating or subscript assignment _means_ calling the setter; there is no other way, because the other guy never obtained a reference to the _original_ array to begin with. That is the same point I make in the second paragraph of my answer. The array can be changed _only_ by replacing it with another array.

Comment: To be fair, the fact that `mutating` methods don't modify `self` but write back to `self` because `self` is a true value (and not a hacky immutable object pretending to be a value) is a pretty big indication of Swift's awesomeness ;-)

Comment: I have a feeling that we totally agree. But I would say it the other way around: the _reason_ you have to declare a mutating method with `mutating` is exactly _because_ this involves writing back to the reference. It is a way of making you acknowledge to the compiler that you understand this fact.

Answer (score 25):

I'd propose a slightly more concise solution than @matt's excellent answer, which again takes advantage of access modifiers. Instead of specifying a separate private variable, and exposing a public/internal computed variable that only provides a getter, you can let Swift do this for you by using `private(set)`:

```
class MyClass {
    private(set) var myItems = [String]()
}
```

This specifies that the *setter* should be private to the current file scope. The *getter* retains the default access level (public/internal) so outside classes can still retrieve a copy of `myItems` (a copy since arrays are structs, so are passed by value*).

But you might then think you can just call a mutating method like `append()` on `myItems`, and in doing so modify it from outside the class (after all, we're getting `var myItems`, not `let myItems`). But Swift is smart enough to recognise that the array should be immutable from outside `MyClass`:

```
let object = MyClass()
object.myItems.append("change me")
//     ^       ~~~~~~
// Immutable value of type '[(String)]' only has mutating members named 'append'
```

So this achieves a very similar effect to the old Objective-C paradigm of maintaining a private `NSMutableArray`, and exposing a public readonly `NSArray` that creates an immutable copy of the private array when called. Much more elegant though, don't you think?



**In actual fact Swift is really smart with passing by value, and may not even make a copy of the array until the point it is modified, and even then may only keep track of the changes (internally). This means you can assign an array with many thousands of items without incurring a massive performance penalty.*

Comment: brilliant that does the business! Matt's answer and explanation is great but the private modifier on set is elegant for sure

Comment: Great! I'm porting a small C# codebase and went from this horror: `private readonly IList<TimelineEvent> _events = new List<TimelineEvent>();
public IReadOnlyList<TimelineEvent> Events => (IReadOnlyList<TimelineEvent>)_events;` to this Swift code `private(set) var events = [TimelineEvent]()`. Awesome.

Comment: How do you do this with a dictionary? It seems that doing `dict[a] = b` is still allowed even when using `private(set)`

Comment: @iosdude How is your `dict` variable declared, and from where are you accessing it (and also, what version of Swift are you using)? The answer above works for dictionaries just as well as any other types.

Comment: @Stuart I'm using Swift 3, here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bcffa7af72b5ae03c2d39c6b19caa39a Is something missing there?

Comment: @iosdude With your code, I get a compiler error on line 16: "Cannot assign through subscript: 'encodedParameters' setter is inaccessible". I would suggest that if that code is compiling for you, it is because you are in fact not using Swift 3, but an earlier version of Swift where the `private` access modifier in fact means it is private _to that file_ (not that _class_) – since both classes are in the same file, both have access to any `private` variables/methods in versions earlier than Swift 3.

Comment: @Stuart It seems that you're right, I've converted my project to Swift 3 one more time to be sure and it's giving me the error now (don't know why it didn't work the first time). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try `NSArray`. The array itself is immutable and the variable can be assigned again.

```
class MyClass{
  var myItems:NSArray
}
```

Comment: You CAN do this. Personally, I would not. You would be foregoing Swift optimizations and type safety features. Using a Swift-native paradigm is a better way to go.